# How to split book image into left and right parts in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a book image like this. I want to split the page into two parts from the middle line (just the left page and the right page).

my thought is to detect the middle line but it didn't work. I want to how to finish this work?

[image: Book Page raw data]

[image: Using opencv in following code]

When I find white space it also has overlapping part.
[image: Find white space]

this is the current version code I use

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
 

filef = 'image.jpg'
image = cv2.imread(filef)

# Convert image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 
# Use canny edge detection
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize=3)
 
# Apply HoughLinesP method to
# to directly obtain line end points
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(
            edges, # Input edge image
            1, # Distance resolution in pixels
            np.pi/180, # Angle resolution in radians
            threshold=600, # Min number of votes for valid line
            minLineLength=600, # Min allowed length of line
            maxLineGap=30 # Max allowed gap between line for joining them
            )
 
lines_list = []
# Iterate over points
for points in lines:
      # Extracted points nested in the list
    x1,y1,x2,y2=points[0]
    # Draw the lines joing the points
    # On the original image
    cv2.line(image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)
    # Maintain a simples lookup list for points
    lines_list.append([(x1,y1),(x2,y2)])
     
# Save the result image
cv2.imwrite(filef[:-4]+'_line.jpg',image)
```

Comment: Did you try to find blank space in the image? blank spaces are those parts of image without any edges. the hough transform proposes some lines- maybe repeated lines- in image and here fails to find leftmose line. So you could not use hough transform.

Comment: thank you. do you mean this method? I also try to use "findContours" but it has an overlapping part, making it hard to find the boundary of each page.

Comment: Run canny edge detector to find edges in image. Then change thresholds to specify white part of image